# How to render a tree graph using GraphView package in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a Flutter project where I need to display a hierarchical tree graph representing the organizational structure. The graph should have a root node for "admin" and under the admin node, there should be manager nodes, and under each manager node, there should be respective user nodes.

I am using the GraphView package (version 1.2.0) for rendering the graph. I have successfully created the nodes and edges.the nodes are overlapping each other

The output of code is[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auVr5.jpg)